# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3] {x}}\,dx,$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate 
>   $ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3] {x}} \,dx,$

So,i've tried doing the substitution $ u=\sqrt[3] {x}$( this was a suggestion by wolfram), but frankly i am reaching a point where it doesn't work . Could help me out ?

Comment: I'd have tried $u = 1+\sqrt[3]x$, which gives $dx=3\sqrt[3] {x^2}du= 3(u-1)^2du$

Comment: Try $u = 1+\sqrt[3] {x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $u = 1 + \sqrt[3]x\implies\mathrm dx = 3x^{\frac23}\mathrm du$. Therefore,

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1 + \sqrt[3]x}\,\mathrm dx\equiv3\int_1^2(u - 1)^2\sqrt u\,\mathrm du = 3\int_1^2 u^{\frac52}\,\mathrm du - 6\int_1^2 u^{\frac32}\,\mathrm du + 3 \int_1^2 u^{\frac 12}\,\mathrm du.$$

Solve the three integrals and plug-in limits.

Answer (score 3):

If $u = \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{x}}$, then the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{x}} \ dx = 6 \int_1^\sqrt{2} u^2 \, (u^2-1)^2du.$$
Now, expand the integrand and integrate a polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]x}= y\implies x=((y^2-1)^3, dx=?$

If $x=0,y=1; x=1, y=?$